# Change color of png image

Tags: .net, colors, png, foreground

I'm looking for a way to change the color of a png programmatically.
So far, all solutiuons I have seen are using getpixel and go through it pixel by pixel.
Actually, I just want to change the foreground color of an image with a transparent background. Is this possible? IS there some kind of palette where the change can be achieved easily for all pixels of a certain color?

Answer (score 1):

Whether a palette is present or not depends upon the PNG colortype.  If the colortype is 3 there is a palette contained in the PLTE chunk, and you can programmatically change it by doing these steps:

1. extract the PLTE chunk
2. change the entry for the foreground color to the new background color
3. recompute the CRC checksum for the PLTE chunk
4. reinsert the PLTE chunk in the image file
5. add a tRNS chunk to make that color transparent.

If the colortype is 0 or 2, then can make the foreground color transparent by adding a tRNS chunk, but if you want to change the underlying color of those pixels to a new background color, you will have to do it pixel by pixel as you already observed.

There's really no need to change the foreground color, though, because when you make it transparent it doesn't really matter what the RGB components contain.